# List folders by date modified

Tags: windows, search, file-management, date

Normally if I want to list everything in the folder by date modified I would type the expression `datemodified:‎<16/03/2014` into the search bar at the top.

This expression lists everything in that file that hasn't been modified since "16/03/2014".

Is there any expression that I can type that will list folders only by date modified and make the computer skip any word documents or loose files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I restrict explorer file searches to folders?

Use the expression `kind:folders`.

> Is there any expression that I can type that will list folders only by date modified?

Use the following search expression:

```
kind:folders AND datemodified:‎<16/03/2014
```

---

#### Advanced Query Syntax

> **Common File Kinds**
>
> Users can also limit their searches to specific types of files, called file kinds. The following table lists the file kinds and offers examples of the syntax used to search for these kinds of files.
>
> [image]

Source [Advanced Query Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)